# How to add macro for controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macros

I want to add macro to controller like active record :has_many

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  macro_to_define_methods :parameters => :here
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module ControllerExtensions
  def do_something(options)
    # do something with options here, e.g. define_method
  end
end
ActionController::Base.extend(ControllerExtensions)


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  do_something :parameters => :here
end
```